# preg_match_all in all input fields

Tags: php, laravel, preg-match-all

I use preg_match_all to find the usernames in the 'body' and save them in a database. How can I find the usernames in several input fields, for example: body, title and article? And how can I save the found references to the database without saving duplicate entries?

```
if ($post) {
            preg_match_all('/\B@(\w+)/', $request->get('body'), $mentionedUsers);

            foreach ($mentionedUsers[1] as $mentionedUser) {

            $foundUser = User::where('username', $mentionedUser)->first();
                if(!$foundUser){
                    continue;
                }
            $foundUserId = $foundUser->id;
            $mentionedUser_save = new Mentioned_post_user;
            $mentionedUser_save->user_id_lead = Auth::user()->id;
            $mentionedUser_save->user_id = $foundUserId;
            $mentionedUser_save->post_id = $post->id;
            $mentionedUser_save->save();

            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you have an example of what you've tried as far as saving from multiple input fields?  Are you using eloquent models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize `whereIn('user_name', $mentionedUsers)` instead of running foreach.

```
if ($post) {
    // assuming this line works and mentioned users are in $mentionedUsers[1]
    preg_match_all('/\B@(\w+)/', $request->get('body'), $mentionedUsers);

    $foundUsers = User::whereIn('username', $mentionedUsers[1])->get();

    if ($foundUsers) {
        foreach ($foundUsers as $foundUser) {
            $foundUserId = $foundUser->id;
            $mentionedUser_save = new Mentioned_post_user;
            $mentionedUser_save->user_id_lead = Auth::user()->id;
            $mentionedUser_save->user_id = $foundUserId;
            $mentionedUser_save->post_id = $post->id;
            $mentionedUser_save->save();
         }
     }
}
```

---

Otherwise, you'd need to get unique values of `$mentionedUsers[1]` with `array_unique()`. (I'd suggest the solution above)

---

Edit: Sorry a thought your problem was different. For your solution, the approach I'd use is combine all inputs.

```
$theString = "$request->body $request->title $request->article";

preg_match_all('/\B@(\w+)/', $theString, $mentionedUsers);    

$userNamesArray = array_unique($mentionedUsers[1]);

$foundUsers = User::whereIn('username', $userNamesArray)->get();
```

Comment: How can i apply the function for multiple colums from the request? Your code work only for „body“ it should also work on „title“ and „articleText“

Comment: @slickness I added how I'd do it, maybe can be done with a better approach, but this is what came to my mind